# How to reshape an unstacked Pandas data frame to "long" form before passing it to a plotting function

Tags: pandas, plotly, plotly-python

I'm trying to make a simple bar plot displaying ratios using the Plotly `px.bar()` function.

I have the following data set:

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame({'Manufacturer':['Ford', 'Ford', 'Mercedes', 'BMW', 'Ford', 'Mercedes', 'BMW', 'Ford', 'Mercedes', 'BMW', 'Ford', 'Mercedes', 'BMW', 'Ford', 'Mercedes', 'BMW', 'Ford', 'Mercedes', 'BMW'],
                          'Metric':['Orders', 'Orders', 'Orders', 'Orders', 'Orders', 'Orders', 'Orders', 'Sales', 'Sales', 'Sales', 'Sales', 'Sales', 'Sales', 'Warranty', 'Warranty', 'Warranty', 'Warranty', 'Warranty', 'Warranty'],
                          'Sector':['Germany', 'Germany', 'Germany', 'Germany', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'Germany', 'Germany', 'Germany', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'Germany', 'Germany', 'Germany', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA'],
                          'Value':[45000, 70000, 90000, 65000, 40000, 65000, 63000, 2700, 4400, 3400, 3000, 4700, 5700, 1500, 2000, 2500, 1300, 2000, 2450],
                          'City': ['Frankfurt', 'Bremen', 'Berlin', 'Hamburg', 'New York', 'Chicago', 'Los Angeles', 'Dresden', 'Munich', 'Cologne', 'Miami', 'Atlanta', 'Phoenix', 'Nuremberg', 'Dusseldorf', 'Leipzig', 'Houston', 'San Diego', 'San Francisco']
                   })
```

I reset the index and create a pivot table, as follows::

```
temp_table = test_df.reset_index().pivot_table(values = 'Value', index = ['Manufacturer', 'Metric', 'Sector'], aggfunc='sum')
```

Then, I create two new data frames:

```
s1 = temp_table.set_index(['Manufacturer','Sector']).query("Metric=='Orders'").Value
s2 = temp_table.set_index(['Manufacturer','Sector']).query("Metric=='Sales'").Value
```

Then, I unstack these data frames:

```
s1.div(s2).unstack()
```

Which gives me:

```
Sector             Germany      USA
Manufacturer
---
BMW               19.117647     11.052632
Ford              42.592593     13.333333
Mercedes          20.454545     13.829787
```

I'd like to be able to make a bar plot using the data above, with `Manufacturer` on the x-axis and colored by `Sector`, as follows:

[image]

To do so, I think I need the data to be in the following long form:

```
Manufacturer       Sector        Ratio
BMW                Germany       19.117647
Ford               Germany       42.592593
Mercedes           Germany       20.454545
BMW                USA           11.052632
Ford               USA           13.333333
Mercedes           USA           13.829787
```

**Question:  how would I reshape the unstacked data above such that I would be able to pass it to the Plotly px.bar() function, which requires the following for the x-axis and y-axis arguments:**

*x (str or int or Series or array-like) – Either a name of a column in data_frame, or a pandas Series or array_like object. Values from this column or array_like are used to position marks along the x axis in cartesian coordinates. Either x or y can optionally be a list of column references or array_likes, in which case the data will be treated as if it were ‘wide’ rather than ‘long’.*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you try `test_df.groupby(['Manufacturer', 'Sector'])['Value'].sum().unstack('Sector').plot.bar()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do not do `unstack`

```
df_out=s1.div(s2).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the bar chart you have up there.

`test_df.groupby(['Manufacturer', 'Sector'])['Value'].sum().unstack('Sector').plot.bar()`

Comment: I can use the .plot.bar() function... but, I want to use the Plotly function, which requires the reshape.